# XamlWriter fails to serialize objects in WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, xaml, serialization

Apparently XamlWriter doesn't works correctly in a WinForms application.

XamlWriter uses MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(object obj). I suppose that there's a problem to determine the full list of properties to serialize.

var ar = new AssemblyReference(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().First());
var str = XamlWriter.Save(ar);

Running an ASP.NET or WPF application I got this result:

```
<AssemblyReference AssemblyName="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
HintPath="file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll" 
SpecificVersion="False" xmlns="clr-namespace:Ivolutia.TypeModel;assembly=ivoTypeModel" />
```

But running the same code in a WinForms application I got this:

```
<AssemblyReference xmlns="clr-namespace:Ivolutia.TypeModel;assembly=ivoTypeModel" />
```

this is the class definition:

```
public class AssemblyReference : DependencyObject
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string HintPath { get; set; }
    public bool SpecificVersion { get; set; }

    public AssemblyReference() { }

    public AssemblyReference(Assembly assembly)
        {
            AssemblyName = assembly.FullName;
            HintPath = assembly.CodeBase;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return AssemblyName;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?  I just created a temp WinForms project and it's outputting:

<AssemblyReference AssemblyName="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" HintPath="file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll" SpecificVersion="False" xmlns="clr-namespace:XamlWriterTester;assembly=XamlWriterTester" />

Edit:
As an aside, is there a reason why plain XML serialization doesn't work for you?